# Error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm transferring products by api. Actually everything was working fine, but I started getting error Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int in.

The data from the API end is the product id and I am registering the product according to this information.

Client::

```
public function GetProductByProductId($productId)
{
    $this->setUrl('https://api.example.com/ws/ProductService.wsdl');
    self::$_parameters['productId'] = $productId;
    return self::$_sclient->GetProductByProductId(self::$_parameters);
}
```

Controller::

```
$service_id = 100;
$productsRaw = $serviceClient->GetProductList();
foreach($productsRaw as $productId){
   $prd = (new serviceClient($service_id))->GetProductByProductId($productId->id);
   if ($prd->result->status == 'failure') {
       $prd = new stdClass();
       $prd->title = $productId->productName;
       ...ect
       $prd->save();
   }
}
```

when i dump($productId) the data, it comes from the api end as below and there is no problem. but when i want to save with GetProductByProductId($productId) i get an error.

```
11 => {#10239
    +"id": 553355693
    +"productSellerCode": "SD250-480GQN"
    +"title": "Afox SD250-480GQN 2.5" 480 GB SATA 3 SSD"
    +"subtitle": "SD250-480GQN"
    +"price": "1221.00"
    +"displayPrice": "1221.00"
    +"isDomestic": false
    +"saleStatus": 2
    +"approvalStatus": 1
    +"stockItems": {#10240
      +"stockItem": {#10241
        +"sellerStockCode": "SD250-480GQN"
        +"optionPrice": "1221.00"
      }
    }
    +"currencyAmount": "1221.00"
    +"currencyType": 1
  }
```

All id's come like this +"id": 553355693
however I keep getting the error "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int in"

Aren't these ids already int() ? I don't understand what should I convert?

Comment: If you could post the rest of the Error Message which would say what file and line number...

Comment: serviceClient.php:233, so that :  return self::$_sclient->GetProductByProductId(self::$_parameters);

Comment: The variable name is a little confusing, `$productId` but then you use it as `$productId->id`

Comment: actually, I am sending the products to a job.
array_push($jobs, new ProductJob($service_id, $product->id));
then I process it in the command product file. I have summarized so as not to write too long. I get only product ids to command via job.

Comment: Does your first method `GetProductByProductId` call itself, or is there another class with that same method but a different signature? This first version appears to take an array `GetProductByProductId(self::$_parameters)` and the second appears to take an int `GetProductByProductId($productId->id)`. I know it is a summary, but it is a little hard to walk what's going on

Comment: GetProductByProductId gets only product ids from GetProductList service. Both of these functions depend on the ClientApi service. Thus, I save the product data from which I have received the product IDs.

Comment: Well, not all ids have to be an int when you convert from a model to an stdClass object. Could you post the stack trace?